# iOS web app icon without glare

Tags: iphone, ios, web-applications

I used this line of code in my web app to add icon:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/ipadicon.png" />
```

but iOS added glare (glass) on icon automatically, and I don't want this.

I know that I can say to iOS for my native app that I don't want glass, but I dont figure out how to do that for web app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change the `rel` to say `apple-touch-icon-precomposed`:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/ipadicon.png" />
```

Comment: If you can't see a change in your icon, note that iOS is a pain with web app icons. You may have to use a different file name or force nocache headers or something to convince iOS to use the prerendered icon.