# Add to home screen - no Reflective shine on icon

Tags: iphone, ios, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS web app icon without glare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719723/ios-web-app-icon-without-glare)

I'm developing a mobile web app.

When on iOS you 'add to home screen' iOS puts a Reflective shine over your predefined icon.
Is there a way to prevent this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the following link...  [Removing Default Gloss on a web app icon](http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/removing-default-gloss-on-a-webapp-icon.211420/)

In the link tag you must set the `rel` value to `"apple-touch-icon-precomposed"`.

Comment: What plist file? The question says it is a web application.

Comment: I need to work on my reading comprehension skills....